# Two sided multiple select box highlight issues ASP Classic

Tags: javascript, select, asp-classic

I am working on a form page which has a two sided multiple select boxes. Box 1 will load from the server all the available dates. When double clicked or select and click >, box 1 options will move to box 2. Box 2 options will be highlighted and selected.
During saved, I added no.selected = true in one of the javascript code to select all the options in box 2 and save it.
But when I enter the page during edit mode, I have some problems:
1. When the page loads, all the selected options will be loaded and highlighted in Box 2. I have to pre-select them by again adding selected=’selected’ in the option tag. This will keep them selected so that when I hit update, I will manage to get their values and update the records according. 
2. But when I hit transfer a single option from box 2 back to box 1, everything is selected and highlighted in box 1 and box 2, is there a way to not select things in box? 
3. I don’t mind box 2 to always remain selected but is there a CSS or something to hide the selected highlights?
4. During save and update, I need the server to manage to request the values from the options tag in box2. What I did is request all the values in a long string, and split it and save. If the options is not selected, I can’t manage to get the values. Again, how to let the options remain selected when moving from Box 1 to Box 2? 
5. Double click once and it will select all in box 1? Please see 
[Double click highlight Box1 issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rixTr.gif)
6. Move back or transfer back it will again highlight in dark grey in box 1? Please see [Transfer back highlight Box 1 issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpHhQ.gif)

To all the gurus, please help me, thank you very much.

```
  <%
sHOL_ID= request("txtHOL_ID")
iPage = request("Page")
sSearch = request("txtSearch")
sModeSub = request("sub")   

if sHOL_ID <> "" then
    sID = sHOL_ID
else
    sID = UCase(reqForm("txtID"))
end if

sName= reqForm("txtName")

sMainURL = "tmholcal.asp?"
sAddURL = "txtSearch=" & server.HTMLEncode(sSearch) & "&Page=" & iPage 

if sModeSub = "up" then
    arr=Split(reqform("ToLB"),",")    

    if Ubound(arr) < 0 then
        response.write "<script language='javascript'>"
        response.write "if (confirm(""Emptying the selected box will delete the Holiday Calendar Code"")==0)"
        response.write " {window.history.back();}"
        response.write "</script>"
    end if

    sSQL = "delete from TMHOL1 where HOL_ID = '" & sID & "'"
    conn.execute sSQL 

    for j = 0 to Ubound(arr)

        sDt_Hol = arr(j)
        j = j + 1
        sPart = arr(j)

        sSQL = "insert into tmhol1 (HOL_ID,NAME,DT_HOL,PART,USER_ID,DATETIME) "
        sSQL = sSQL & "values ("
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & pRTIN(sID) & "',"       
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & pRTIN(sName) & "',"     
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & fdate2(sDt_Hol) & "',"      
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & pRTIN(sPart) & "',"
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & session("USERNAME") & "'," 
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & fdatetime2(Now()) & "'"
        sSQL = sSQL & ") "
        conn.execute sSQL
    Next

        sAddURL = "txtSearch=" & sSearch & "&Page=" & iPage 

    call confirmBox("Update Successful!", sMainURL&sAddURL&"&txtHOL_ID=" & sID & "")

elseif sModeSub = "save" then

    if sID = "" then
        alertbox(" Holiday Calendar Code cannot be empty! ")
    end if

    arr=Split(reqform("ToLB"),",")    

    for i = 0 to Ubound(arr)
        sDt_Hol = arr(i)
            i = i + 1
        sPart = arr(i)

        sSQL = "insert into tmhol1 (HOL_ID,NAME,DT_HOL,PART,USER_ID,DATETIME) "
        sSQL = sSQL & "values ("
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & pRTIN(sID) & "',"       
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & pRTIN(sName) & "',"     
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & fdate2(sDt_Hol) & "',"      
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & pRTIN(sPart) & "',"
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & session("USERNAME") & "'," 
        sSQL = sSQL & "'" & fdatetime2(Now()) & "'"
        sSQL = sSQL & ") "
        conn.execute sSQL

        call confirmBox("Save Successful!", sMainURL&sAddURL&"&txtHOL_ID=" & sID & "")  
    next
end if

function ShowAvailDates(sParam)
Set rs=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql="Select * from tmhol "
sql=sql & "order by dt_hol"
rs.open sql, conn
if len(sParam) > 0  then

    do while not rs.eof

            bflag=true

            Set rs1=server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            sql="Select * from tmhol1 "
            sql = sql & " where hol_id = '" & sParam & "'"
            sql = sql & " order by dt_hol"
            rs1.open sql, conn
                do while not rs1.eof 

                    if fdate2(rs("DT_HOL")) = fdate2(rs1("DT_HOL")) then
                        bflag= false  
                        exit do
                    end if
                    rs1.movenext
                loop

            if bflag = true then
                response.write "<option value='" & rs("DT_HOL") & "," & rs("PART") & "'>" & rs("DT_HOL") & " - " & rs("PART") & "</option>"
            end if    

       rs.movenext 
   loop 
else  
    do while not rs.eof

       if year(rs("DT_HOL")) = year(date) then
            response.write "<option value='" & rs("DT_HOL") & "," & rs("PART") & "'>" & rs("DT_HOL") & " - " & rs("PART") & "</option>"
        end if

        rs.movenext 
    loop
    pCloseTables(rs)
end if 
end function

Set rstTMHOL1 = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")    
sSQL = "select * from TMHOL1 where HOL_ID ='" & sID & "'" 
rstTMHOL1.Open sSQL, conn, 3, 3
    if not rstTMHOL1.eof then
        sName = rstTMHOL1("Name")
   end if
%>

</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- #include file="include/header.asp" -->
    <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <!-- #include file="include/sidebar_tm.asp" -->

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>Holiday Calendar Details</h1>
        </section>
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="box">
                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                        <div class="box-body ">
                            <form name="form1" class="form-horizontal" action="tmholcal_det.asp" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Page" value='<%=iPage%>' />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Holiday Calendar Code : </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <% if sHOL_ID <> "" then %>
                                        <span class="mod-form-control"><% response.write sHOL_ID%> </span>
                                        <input type="hidden" id="txtID" name="txtID" value="<%=sHOL_ID%>" />
                                        <%else%>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="txtID" name="txtID" value="<%=sID%>" maxlength="30" style="text-transform: uppercase" input-check />
                                        <% end if %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name : </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="txtName" name="txtName" value="<%=server.Htmlencode(sName)%>" maxlength="30">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Year : </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <%if sSHFPAT_ID <> "" then%>
                                        <span class="mod-form-control"><% response.write sYear%> </span>
                                        <input type="hidden" id="selYear" value="<%=sYear%>" />
                                        <%else%>
                                        <select name="selYear" id="selYear" class="form-control">
                                            <%For i = 1 to 34 
                                                    selyear = Cint(2016) + Cint(i)
                                            %>
                                            <option value="<%=selyear%>" <%if sYear = selyear then%>Selected<%end if%>><%=selyear%></option>
                                            <%Next%>
                                        </select>
                                        <% end if %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>-->
                                <div>
                                    <table id="example1">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="5%"></td>
                                                <td width="20%" style="padding: 7px"><b>Available Dates :</b>
                                                    <select multiple size="15" style="width: 405px;" name="FromLB" id="FromLB" ondblclick="move(this.form.FromLB,this.form.ToLB)">
                                                        <%  
                                                            ShowAvailDates(sHOL_ID)
                                                        %>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="3%" style="padding: 9px" align="center">
                                                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 50px" onclick="move(this.form.FromLB, this.form.ToLB)" value="   >   ">
                                                    <br>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 50px" onclick="move(this.form.ToLB, this.form.FromLB)" value="   <   ">
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="30%" style="padding: 11px"><b>Selected : </b>
                                                    <select multiple size="15" style="width: 405px;" name="ToLB" id="ToLB" ondblclick="move(this.form.ToLB,this.form.FromLB)">
                                                        <%  Set rstTMHOL1 = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")    
                                                            sSQL = "select * from TMHOL1 where HOL_ID ='" & sID & "'" 
                                                            rstTMHOL1.Open sSQL, conn, 3, 3

                                                            do while not rstTMHOL1.eof 
                                                                response.write "<option value='" & rstTMHOL1("DT_HOL") & "," & rstTMHOL1("PART") & "' selected='selected'>" & rstTMHOL1("DT_HOL") & " - " & rstTMHOL1("PART") & "</option>"  
                                                                rstTMHOL1.movenext
                                                            loop

                                                        %>

                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-footer">
                                    <%if sHOL_ID <> "" then %>
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delholcal" data-hol_id="<%=server.htmlencode(sHOL_ID)%>"
                                        class="btn btn-danger pull-left" style="width: 90px">Delete</a>
                                        <button type="submit" name="sub" value="up" class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="width: 90px">Update</button>
                                    <%else%>
                                    <button type="submit" name="sub" value="save" class="btn btn-default pull-right"
                                        style="width: 90px">
                                        Save</button>
                                    <%end if%>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                         </div>
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal-delholcal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="del-content">
                                <!--- Content ---->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    <!-- #include file="include/footer.asp" -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
<!-- input-check -->
<script src="plugins/Custom/input-check.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#modal-delholcal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var hol_id = button.data('hol_id')
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(hol_id)
    showDelmodal(hol_id)
})

function showDelmodal(str){
    var xhttp;

    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("del-content").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "tmholcal_del.asp?txtstring="+str, true);
    xhttp.send();

}
</script>
<script>
function move(tbFrom, tbTo) {
    var arrFrom = new Array(); var arrTo = new Array(); 
    var arrLU = new Array();
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < tbTo.options.length; i++) {
        arrLU[tbTo.options[i].text] = tbTo.options[i].value;
        arrTo[i] = tbTo.options[i].text;
    }
    var fLength = 0;
    var tLength = arrTo.length;
    for(i = 0; i < tbFrom.options.length; i++) {
        arrLU[tbFrom.options[i].text] = tbFrom.options[i].value;
        if (tbFrom.options[i].selected && tbFrom.options[i].value != "") {
            arrTo[tLength] = tbFrom.options[i].text;
            tLength++;
        } else {
            arrFrom[fLength] = tbFrom.options[i].text;
            fLength++;
        }
    }

    tbFrom.length = 0;
    tbTo.length = 0;
    var ii;

    for(ii = 0; ii < arrFrom.length; ii++) {
        var no = new Option();
        no.value = arrLU[arrFrom[ii]];
        no.text = arrFrom[ii];
        no.selected = true;
        tbFrom[ii] = no;

    }

    for(ii = 0; ii < arrTo.length; ii++) {
        var no = new Option();
        no.value = arrLU[arrTo[ii]];
        no.text = arrTo[ii];
        no.selected = true;   // I enable it because when 
        tbTo[ii] = no;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I got the flow wrong. I should have remove all the no.selected=true in the javascript code and add the following Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnUp').click(function () {
     $('#ToLB').each(function () {
        $('#ToLB option').attr("selected", "selected");
        });
     });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSave').click(function () {
     $('#ToLB').each(function () {
        $('#ToLB option').attr("selected", "selected");
        });
     });
});
```

Basically the Jquery will select all the options when btnSave or btnUpdate is clicked.

Hence, the server will manage to pick up the values of the option tags.